# Why select option change event can't have this and event.target to get selected value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In select option change event,why can't we get this or event.target to get selected value instead of writing clumsy code like `$( "select option:selected" )` to get selected value ?

Comment: `this.value` or `event.target.value` should work.

Comment: It works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/a6gkggwx/1/

Comment: Make sure you bind the `change` event to the `select`, not `option`.

Comment: I know but my question is why we cant get selected value and selected dom properties via this or event.target like we use in other text and all..

Comment: What makes you think we can't? I just showed that you can.

Comment: If it's not working for you, you need to post the code.

Comment: Barmar i m facing problem here is i need to get the selected dom property like data-* attribute from it

Comment: You need to explain that in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggession i will include it. Barmar

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Pure JavaScript

If you want a pure JavaScript approach, then use the `event.target`.  To quote the official MDN documentation...

> The target property of the Event interface is a reference to the object onto which the event was dispatched. (Source: [**MDN Web Docs: Event.target**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).)

Since that gives us the element selected, all we then need is the [**`value`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) attribute, and getting the text display would be nothing more than `event.target[event.target.selectedIndex].text`...

```js
function getSelectedValue(event) {
   console.log("Value: " + event.target.value + "; Display: " + event.target[event.target.selectedIndex].text + ".");
}
```

```html
<select onchange="getSelectedValue(event)">
    <option selected disabled>--Pick an Option--</option>
    <option value="blue1">Blueberry</option>
    <option value="rasp2">Raspberry</option>
    <option value="straw3">Strawberry</option>
</select>
```

Using the above approach, it would be trivial to update it to add in other attributes of the selection option value, all in pure JavaScript.

### jQuery

If you want a jQuery approach, then try using the [`:selected`](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) query term...

```js
$("#selector").on('change', function(){
    console.log("Value: " + $(this).val() + "; Display: " + $(this).find('option:selected').text() + ".");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selector">
        <option selected disabled>--Pick an Option--</option>
        <option value="blue1">Blueberry</option>
        <option value="rasp2">Raspberry</option>
        <option value="straw3">Strawberry</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I am referring the Jquery here anyway you approach is give me insight how plain javascript on the same very much for your knowledge sharing.

Comment: You're right, your question is tagged jQuery, but doesn't mention jQuery.  Google recommended this question as the top answer, if you search for either jQuery or JavaScript, so, I thought I'd give the JS answer, just in case for future searchers!  More people will be likely to upvote a question if there's a good answer. =)

Answer (score 5):

```js
$("select").on('change', function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
  console.log($(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-attribute')); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option data-attribute="a">1</option>
  <option data-attribute="b">2</option>
  <option data-attribute="c">3</option>
  <option data-attribute="d">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But the thing is i need to get dom to read data attributes in selected dom

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the selected value, but of course you can get the element and the event.target.

```
<select onchange="mySelectOnchange(this, event)"></select>

function mySelectOnchange(elm, e) {
   // **
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It exists... take a look at this code for example

```js
var selectElem = document.getElementById('select');

selectElem.addEventListener('change', onSelect_change);

function onSelect_change(domEvent){
 // get the selected value :
 var selectedValue = domEvent.target[domEvent.target.selectedIndex].value;
  // you can also do it using domEvent.target.value but the other solution allows you to get every option's property you want 
 
 console.log("Selected: " + selectedValue);
}
```

```html
<select id="select" name="select">
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

Hope it helps ;)

PS: have a look on http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp if you want more examples

Answer (score 1):

The only property that's automatically transferred from the selected option to the `<select>` element itself is the value, because that's the main purpose of selecting an option from a drop-down menu. Other attributes like `data-*` are not automatically copied, because it's possible for the `<select>` to have its own attributes, e.g.

```
<select id="x" data-name="select">
    <option value="1" data-name="option1">1</option>
    <option value="2" data-name="option2">2</option>
</select>
```

It wouldn't make sense for `$("#x").data("name")` to return the name of the selected option instead of the name of the `<select>`.

Answer (score -1):

```
<select onchange="getSelectedValue(this)"></select>
...
function getSelectedValue(select) {
   console.log(select.value)
}
```

Comment: When adding an answer to a four year old question with an accepted answer it is important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. Code only answers can generally be improved by adding explanation for how and why they work.