# How to log selected value of a html DropDown element?

Tags: javascript, html

I am setting up online experiments in PCIbex, which works on a combination of JavaScript and Html. I am trying to embed a HTML file in the main .js script. The problem is that some things do not get logged. The situation is as follows: In the main js file I call an HTML file that contains radio, input and dropdown elements that look like this:

```
<p><font size="4">4. Stelle Dir vor, die Leiter (s. unten) repräsentiert den relativen Sozialstatus der Menschen in Deutschland. An der Spitze der Leiter stehen Menschen mit relativ hohem Status – diejenigen, die das meiste Geld, die beste Bildung und die angesehensten Arbeitsplätze haben. Ganz unten sind Menschen mit relativ niedrigem Status – beispielsweise als arbeitslos Gemeldete. Relativ weit unten zu verorten wären auch diejenigen, die nur wenig Geld verdienen, einen niedrigen Bildungstand haben, und / oder Berufe ausüben, die die Gesellschaft als eher wenig respektabel ansieht.
<br>
<be>
Wo würdest Du Dich auf dieser Leiter einordnen? Wähle bitte die Sprosse, die Deinem empfundenen Sozialstatus am ehesten entspricht.
<br> </font></p>

<img src="https://amor.cms.hu-berlin.de/~p/Leiter.jpeg" alt="Leiter" border="0" width=300 height=400>
  
<p><font size="4">Deine Antwort:</font>
<select  name="Socialstatus" required="true" id="Socialstatus">
    <option value ="Bitte">Bitte eine Option ausw&auml;hlen</option>  
    <option value="10">A</option>
    <option value="9">B</option>
    <option value="8">C</option>
    <option value="7">D</option>
    <option value="6">E</option>
    <option value="5">F</option>
    <option value="4">G</option>
    <option value="3">H</option>
    <option value="2">I</option>
    <option value="1">J</option>
</select>
```

In this case, the selection of the 'Socialstatus' DropDown element is not logged at all in the results file. I have tried introducing an  element with a function that contains console.log(), but this did not work.

The second problem is that when such a DropDown requires an input box after selection, the initial selection does not get logged either. What I mean is that once the second option is selected, an input box appears and the only thing that gets logged for the entire element is the content of the input, but not the value of the DropDown element.

```
<p><font size="4">6. Mit welcher Sprache bist Du zuhause aufgewachsen?</font></p>
<select id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();">
    <option value ="Bitte">Bitte eine Option ausw&auml;hlen</option>
    <option value="Dialekt">A. Dialekt</option>
    <option value="Umgangssprache">B. Umgangssprache</option>
    <option value="Gepflegtes Hochdeutsch">C. Gepflegtes Hochdeutsch</option>
    <option value="Alle">D. Alle</option>
    <option value="B und C">E. B und C</option>
    <option value="A und C">F. A und C</option>
    <option value="A und B">G. A und B</option>
</select>

<input name="original_dialect" placeholder="Bitte schreibe auf, mit welchen Dialekten Du aufgewachsen bist" size="55" class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" id="textboxes">
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function changeFunc() {
   var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
   var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    if((selectedValue=="Dialekt")|(selectedValue=="Alle")|(selectedValue=="A und C")|(selectedValue=="A und B")){
     $('#textboxes').show();
      document.getElementById("textboxes").className="obligatory";
    }
    else {
     $('#textboxes').hide();
      document.getElementById("textboxes").className="form-control";
    }
  }
</script>
```

I would be very grateful to find out whether I am doing something wrong here. I am not experienced when it comes to programming languages and so I apologize if this question is trivial.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I am not **entierly sure** what you are trying to do. But to get the value of a dropdown in a `<select>` you can use `document.getElementById("Socialstatus").value;` This should get whatever value is currently selected.

Comment: You can also use the event.target to get the value, [I have an answer elsewhere that shows how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64702449/2430549).  Good luck!

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and DOM API?

Comment: @Gunnarhawk. Thank you so much. I am not sure how I would incorporate this in the code. Do I need to define a variable that saves the value of the suggested command? Thank you!